# How to automatically trigger pasting a value in the next row on worksheet 2 when something is pasted into a cell on worksheet 1

Tags: excel, vba

I have two cells in one worksheet: A barcode scan (A1) and then a date/time cell (B2).
Basically I am trying to have it so when a barcode is scanned on sheet (Scans), it automatically logs to the next worksheet in the next available row (Scansraw). Then it clears the barcode for the next scan.

I have a code below. There is two parts. The sub barcodescans and then the PrivateSub.
I can get both parts to work individually, but not together.

How can I get these to work together? Or if there is an alternative method of accomplishing the above.

Here is my code:

```
    Sub barcodescans()

    ws_output = "Scansraw"

    next_row = Sheets(ws_output).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

    Sheets(ws_output).Cells(next_row, 1).Value = Range("A1").Value
    Sheets(ws_output).Cells(next_row, 2).Value = Range("B1").Value


    Range("A1").ClearContents
End Sub



   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        Call barcodescans
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You very likely need to disable events otherwise the Change event will fire again and again as you clear cell A1

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    
    On Error GoTo EH
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        Call barcodescans
    End If

EH:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```